# How to convert Tensorflow model.json to model.pb file

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, computer-vision, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow.js

I am trying to convert tensor-flow models which are in model.json to model.pb format. Tried to find good sources but didn't get any. I have model.json file along with binary weight files. Initially I converted them so that it can work on browser but now needed them as .pb files. Please help.

https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_saved_model

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge we do not support going to that from JS.

Only Python savedModel -> JS right now so that one can use in browser environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the TensorFlow.js Graph Model Converter:

https://github.com/patlevin/tfjs-to-tf

tfjs_graph_converter path/to/js/model path/to/frozen/model.pb

Answer (score 0):

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.models import model_from_json

# Load the JSON model architecture
json_model_path = 'path/to/your/model.json'
with open(json_model_path, 'r') as json_file:
    loaded_model_json = json_file.read()

loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)

# Load the weights
weights_path = 'path/to/your/model_weights.h5'
loaded_model.load_weights(weights_path)

# Save the entire model in the .pb format
output_pb_path = 'path/to/your/model.pb'
tf.saved_model.save(loaded_model, output_pb_path)
```

Replace 'path/to/your/model.json', 'path/to/your/model_weights.h5', and 'path/to/your/model.pb' with the actual paths to your JSON model architecture file, weights file, and the desired output path for the .pb file.